# The Executable file contains incomplete bitcode error. To compile binaries with complete bitcode, open Xcode and choose archive in the product menu

Tags: ios, bitcode

I tried disabling the bitcode in build settings of project file and for all third party libraries.
For libraries  Iam getting error "Your app can't contain standalone executables or libraries, other than CFBundleExecutable or supported bundles."

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in my project. I have fixed this by below two solutions (Solution 1 and Solution 2).

## Solution 1

You can disable bitcode by adding following lines to the iOS app project's .csproj file immediately before the closing  tag.

```
<Target Name="BeforeCodesign">
  <Exec Command="$(_SdkDevPath)\Toolchains\XcodeDefault.xctoolchain\usr\bin\bitcode_strip %(_Frameworks.FullPath) -r -o %(_Frameworks.FullPath)" />
</Target>
```

## Solution 2

In your .csproj for your iOS application(or native framework application, if you are facing this issue in native framework project), search for the PropertyGroup for the release configuration that you need to turn off bit code, like below:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhone' ">
```

Within that group, see if a MtouchEnableBitcode already exists and edit it, otherwise add below line:

```
<MtouchEnableBitcode>false</MtouchEnableBitcode>
```

## Solution 3

Build the applications with Xcode 9 and the latest version of Xamarin.iOS.

**Reason:**
Invalid Bundle - The app cannot be processed because options not allowed to be embedded in bitcode are detected in the submission. It is likely that you are not building the app with the toolchain provided in Xcode. for more detail [click here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/invalid-bundle-bitcode/)